# Perl Split Function - How to assign a specify array value to a variable in one line

Tags: perl, split, one-liner

Is this a way of using a one-liner to assign an array value to a variable using the split function.

I have the following code. This works.

```
my @Fields = split(',',@_[0]);
my $Unit = @Fields[2];
```

Wondering if it could be written in one like the following, they are returning syntax errors.

```
my $Unit = split(',',@_[0])[2];

my $Unit = @(split(',',@_[0]))[2];
```

Comment: You should use a scalar sigil when referring to an array slice of 1 element: `my $unit = $fields[2]`. Same with `split(',',$_[0])`. When using `@_`, it is better to copy the value to avoid changing it. E.g. `my $arg = shift; my @fields = split ',', $arg;`

Answer (score 3):

Your second one is very close. Drop that leading `@`:

```perl
my $Unit = (split(',', $_[0]))[2];
```

(Note `$_[0]` instead of the one-element array slice `@_[0]`... if you have `use warnings;` in effect like you should, that would give you one.)

Comment: If you have a lot of fields, you might consider `(split(',', $_[0], 4))[2]` to avoid it returning a longer list than is needed. What would normally be the 4th, 5th, 6th, etc. elements are all part of the 4th one with that length modifier.